# Adding Admin authentication in rails API packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an API package in rails 3 that will respond to either json or xml.

I have two resources - categories and a nested resource, articles. Now, the app will have only one user ie the admin!

Only the admin can login and create,update and delete categories and articles. There will be no other user ie there are no other user profile. The app will contain a page listing all the categories and another page under categories listing the articles.Anyone other than the admin can only read the articles!

How can i achieve this kind of authentication while building a Rails API

P.S - I am completely new to rails!!This is the first API package i am building.So help will be very much appreciated!

P.P.S-I am using rails 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a very simple authetication, there's HTTP authentication. There's another one that involves the use of `has_secure_password`. This [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1) should get you started.

For API authentication using api_keys/access_token, see this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast).